# Unable to Run my Selenium code Using Browser Stack

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, browserstack

[image]I have a Simple Selenium code and i am Trying to run it on Remote Browser(Browser Stack).Trying to Open a Browser and Logging in to the application. So my code is running and i am able to open the browser but unable to log in. What am i doing wrong. 
This is the Error message displayed

here https://www.hzelectric.com/

PASSED: URLCHECK

FAILED: ARegistrationandLogout

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.testngsample.SampleTest.ARegistrationandLogout(SampleTest.java:40)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481). Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the test script has not initialised the WebDriver object in the **ARegistrationandLogout** test method. I suggest adding the capabilities and initialise the WebDriver instance again in the **ARegistrationandLogout** test method.

[Use Capabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAbCg.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are initialising the WebDriver instance in method - 'URLCHECK' and using the same instance in method - 'ARegistrationandLogout' (which is not initialised, hence [NullPointerException](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Preventing_NullPointerException) is printed)

Since you are using TestNG, you need to do something like this..

```
public class UnitTestClass {

public WebDriver webDriver = null;
public DesiredCapabilities caps = null;

@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest() {
    try {
        caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("os", "Windows");
        caps.setCapability("os_version", "8.1");
        caps.setCapability("browser", "Firefox");
        caps.setCapability("browser_version", "63.0 beta");

        webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://<USERNAME>:<ACCESS_KEY>@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub"), caps);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} // BEFORE TEST END

@Test
public void UnitTest() {
    webDriver.get("https://www.google.com/");
} // TEST END

@AfterClass
public void afterClass() {
    if(webDriver != null){
        webDriver.quit();
    }
} // AFTER TEST END }
```

I would recommend you to review these online resources - [#guru99](https://www.guru99.com/all-about-testng-and-selenium.html), [#ToolsQA](http://toolsqa.com/testng/what-is-testng/), [#TestNG_Docs](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)

I see you are trying to test on [BrowserStack](https://automate.browserstack.com). They have a detailed documentation around the same. You can view the TestNG-BrowserStack doc [here](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/testng). They have a sample GIT repository as well - [#TestNG-BrowserStack-GIT-Repo](https://github.com/browserstack/testng-browserstack)

Comment: Thanks Worked like a Charm. I  initialised  the webdriver again and worked for me